# Is there any difference between “a ... sense of purpose” and “a sense of ... purpose”?

Tags: meaning, expressions

There’s an English-Japanese dictionary giving identical Japanese words for “a common sense of purpose” and “a sense of common purpose.” I’m wondering if both of the expressions are the same in meaning.

Just out of curiosity, I used google search and found “a spiritual sense of purpose” (37,000 hits) and “a sense of spiritual purpose” (15,000 hits).

I’d like to know if both kinds of expressions are the same in meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both can mean that everyone has a shared purpose. But *a sense of common purpose* can also mean that one only *thinks* everyone has a shared purpose.

So you can *build a common sense of purpose* within a team. Or you can *instill a sense of common purpose* into a competitor.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the nouns being modified:

> [**sense**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sense?show=0&t=1327202777) : a meaning conveyed or intended
>
> [**purpose**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purpose) : something set up as an object or end to be attained

Looking at the grouping:

> {**common sense**} of purpose : {shared understanding} of the goal
>
> sense of {**common purpose**} : understanding of a {shared goal}

The difference is subtle, but it's there. Same with the second set of phrases:

> {**spiritual sense**} of purpose : {sacred intention} toward some goal
>
> sense of {**spiritual purpose**} : understanding of a {sacred goal}

The distinction is perhaps less clear in this case, but *spiritual* is modifying a different noun in each sentence.